# How can I pass a variable to a jekyll layout?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I don't understand how to pass a variable to a Jekyll layout. I have a markdown file with this header:

```yaml
---
layout: post
next_tutorial: next_tutorial_name
---
```

And then, in the post layout, I have this:

```html
---
layout: default
---
<article id="postBody">
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ page.date | date_to_string }}</p>

    {{ content }}

    {% if site.next_tutorial %}
    <h2>{{ site.next_tutorial }}</h2>
    {% endif %}
</article>
```

But the h2 element never appears. I tried removing the if, but the result is the same. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are calling the *"header of a markdown file"* actually have a name in Jekyll, and this is called the [***Front Matter***](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/).

And the elements of the front matter can be accessed via the `page` variable, as pointed [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/#custom-variables) and [there](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#global-variables).

So, your layout should read:

```html
---
layout: default
---
<article id="postBody">
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ page.date | date_to_string }}</p>

    {{ content }}

    {% if page.next_tutorial %}
    <h2>{{ page.next_tutorial }}</h2>
    {% endif %}
</article>
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!